# Is there such a thing as IDP -> to IDP -> authentication? (SAML2)

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0

Is there such a think as IDP to IDP authentication?

Where I work we have this setup:

[Client IDP] <----> [Work SP]

-- Client gets authenticated thru their portal

-- Client navigates to our site, because we are setup as sp then they are authenticated to our site via saml2

What they want

[Client IDP] <----> [Work SP]

[Work IDP] <----> [VendorSP]

-- Client gets authenticated thru their portal

-- Client navigates to our site, because we are setup as sp then they are authenticated to our site via saml2

-- Client navigates to vendor thru out site and are authenticated via Work IDP.

If everything was going thru a single IDP this would be easy.

Is what I'm being asked to do even possible? I've never heard of anything like IPD to IDP communication. It would be like logging into Google with your Apple account..

If anyone has some insight or advice I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Every popular SAML tool that I am aware of, commercial or otherwise, can generally act as a service provider and an identity provider. Some tools out there can act natively as a federation "hub". That model looks something like this using the "names" you provided:

```
Client IdP --> SP|Work|IdP --> Vendor SP
```

The "special sauce" that a product that supports the hub concept is that the product manages the forwarding of identity attributes via another assertion on its own as a singular flow, as compared to a product that completes the Client IdP to the Work SP transaction, hands it off to some external mechanism which turns around and starts a new federation from the Work IdP to the Vendor SP, resulting in something that looks like this:

```
Client IdP --> Work SP --> user service --> Work IdP --> Vendor SP
```

The products that provide for the hub model *generally* can support **Vendor** SP-initiated transactions that reach all the way back to the Client IdP without any user interaction with only a redirection occuring at the Work hub. The way I've seen the "user service" model built is with a dock or portal where the user clicks on something to initiate the second transaction.

All that is to say... As long as you have a "common" SAML product, you can certainly achieve the end state you desire, however the model you have available to you is dependent on the tool you have.

Comment: This makes sense! I'm not sure what platform our client is using, maybe F5.  We are using keycloak inhouse.  Thanks for the response!

Answer (score -1):

This is actually quite common.

The technical phrase is R-STS.

The notation “(Server — STS / R-STS)” indicates whether the IDP can act as a IDP itself (i.e. clients can use this for authentication) and whether the IDP can act as an intermediate step on the path to the final IDP.

Lots of IDP can be both e.g. ADFS can be both a SP and a CP (Claims provider).

So if you had:

App --> IDP1 --> IDP2

then IDP1 is a CP to the app and a SP to IDP2.

How it would normally work e.g.

- App --> IDP1
- IDP1 shows Home Realm Discovery screen
- User chooses IDP2
- User authenticates on IDP2
- SAML token returned downstream to the app

Comment: In SAML there is no STS. SAML only knows the concept of an IdP-Proxy.

SP <-- SAML --> IdP-Proxy <-- SAML --> IdP

IdP-Proxy can only work with SP-initiated SSO flow.

SP --> SAML AuthnRequest 1 --> IdP-Proxy --> SAML AuthnRequest 2 --> IdP
SP <-- SAML AuthResponse 1 <-- IdP-Proxy <-- SAML Response 2 <--- IdP

Comment: Some products can act as a 'federation hub', where the authentication at the SAML IdP can be delegated further to an upstream authentication server via other means / technologies like SAML , OIDC, WS-Federation
e.g. 
SAML SP <-- SAML --> SAML IdP / OIDC relying party <-- OIDC --> OIDC provider
SAML SP <-- SAML --> SAML IdP  / SAML SP <-- SAML --> SAML IdP
SAML SP <-- SAML --> SAML IdP / WS-Federation relying party <-- WS-Federation --> WS-Federation issuing party

Comment: Both of the comments from @BernhardThalmayr are true... I would note that there are not actually many products out there that provide for the proxy model. The hub model described is becoming more and more common, but is still not ubiquitous. Lastly, I've never heard of _rbrayb's_ "notation" called “(Server — STS / R-STS)” in SAML.

Comment: https://mohamadhalabi.com/2012/12/17/adfs-2-0-by-example-part1-adfs-as-ip-sts-and-r-sts/